# Firebase function triggered twice

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I need to create a Firebase user which has 3 related dataset saved in the Realtime Database arranged like below.

```
root
  |
  x - dataset1
  |
  x - dataset2
  |
  x - whatever
  |   |
  |   x - dataset3
  |
```

The user is created by a firebase function having the following schema:

```
exports.createNewUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const userData = {
        ...
    };

    const data1 = {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2",
        ...
    };

    const data2 = {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2",
        ...
    };

    const data3 = {
        "key1" : "value1",
        "key2" : "value2",
        ...
    };

    admin.auth().createUser(userData)
    .then(userRecord => (
        var promises = [];

        promises.push(admin.database().ref(`dataset1/${userId}`).set(data1));
        promises.push(admin.database().ref(`dataset2/${userId}`).set(data2));
        promises.push(admin.database().ref(`whatever/dataset3/${userId}`).set(data3));

        return Promise.all(promises);
    )}
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).end();
    })
}
```

The strange thing is that when the function is launched first time it works perfectly, but everytime after the first it's triggered twice.

So far I solved moving "data3" under the root but is it a kind of bug or did I do something wrong?

thanks in advance

** EDIT **

@Doug Stevenson I tried your suggestion but unfortunately no way, here are some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you observing that it's triggered more than once? If you're looking at the console log, refresh that page and see if the duplicates still appear. If they don't, it's just because of a bug in the console.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson from the function log in the firebase console.

Comment: And, if you reload it, the duplicates still appear? HTTP triggers should never duplicate unless you actually call it twice.  HTTP triggers give an at-most-once guarantee.

Comment: Actually in the reality the function returns a message: in case of success displayed by snackbar and in case of error displayed by a dialog. So after the first time I can see both (the email is already used); this situation is confirmed by logs. Just to be sure, when you say reload do you mean page log? Console bug is compatible with the fact events timestamps are slightly different (few milliseconds)? Anyway I'll git it a try. Thanks

Comment: I'm talking about the Firebase console in the Functions product.  I would be incredibly shocked if an HTTP request was internally duplicated.  That goes against the at-most-once guarantee for HTTP triggers.

Comment: I guess it's not because, as I said, moving the 3rd dataset directly under the root things seems to work; anyway I'll give it a try and come back to you.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I edited my question adding some screenshots.

Comment: I don't really have anything to add.  Without seeing your code that invokes the function, we can't rule out that it may be invoking it twice.